# Has synthetic biology created new plants or animals as of 2013?

Tags: zoology, botany, synthetic-biology

I've seen a [Ted.com talk where the speaker suggests that modern science can create new micro organisms](http://www.ted.com/talks/craig_venter_unveils_synthetic_life.html), like bacteria with a pre- defined new set of traits. But has anyone create a new species of plants or animals using synthetic DNA yet? If so, what are their names?

Comment: None yet as far as I know.

Comment: Can you define "new"? Is a genetically modified species "new"?

Comment: nope, only bacteria as of this time.

Answer (score 4):

**Answering your question**

Well, considering there is a plethora of facilities that deal with the cloning of plants and animals, as well as altering specific DNA in order to create a better plant or animal. Tests have been done with rats to try and create stronger and smarter rats, and tests have been done on countless other animals to try to develop immunity to dementia and Alzheimers. In the agricultural industries of the world, new types of corn, tomatoes, rice, and other types of crops are engineered on a daily basis, and new versions of these plants are made very commonly. The problem, however, is that a vast quantity of these plants are rejected from being planted. Some plants that are engineered either taste too bad, or they are less efficient than the plant at which they were modifying. As far as inventing a new species, you have to be more specific as to what you are asking. If science creates a new animal from another animal, it is likely of the same family and genus, like breeding a dog from another dog. Creating another type of mammal or reptile or bacteria that isn't part of a specific genus would be a breakthrough, as I am sure that all types of cloning and scientific pairing have been done to the same general Genus and Species... I am assuming, however, that it will be possible to engineer lifeforms at the molecular level by the next 50 to 100 years, as science and technology is getting more and more advanced. So, by the next few centuries, it would only seem logical to assume that new species would be created. However, the practice of creating new species, or even operating a laboratory/facility that deals with the concept, is illegal in a large number of countries, and has several guidelines in others.

*I am only 13, so if any of this information is to be used anywhere else, I would advise not to cite me as a credible source. All this information is from my knowledge, and my knowledge is from school studies and personal readings. This is all my information, though. If any wording sounds similar to another source, keep in mind that one human brain functions similarly to another on several accounts and coincidences are often found.  I can assure you that if the documented information above is verified by plagiarism experts as my own wording, as I have taken the liberty to scan my own work. I hope I answered your question, and I am sorry for the long disclaimer ranting of this paragraph.*

Comment: If you have referred to a source, it's okay to paraphrase as long as you cite where it came from.

Comment: hey its great to see someone 13 starting to contribute here!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. 
At this moment (2016) the are only two synthetic organisms that are being constructed or have been constructed.

The first is a synthetic Mycoplasma genitalium.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_laboratorium Made by venter

The second is synthetic yeast, S. cerevisiae http://syntheticyeast.org/

There has been talk of building a synthetic human genome... but that is only talk.